# Bulk Attach Media Files To WooCommerce Products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have currently uploaded all of my product images to the server using FTP, registered them using the Add From Server Plugin. I have also uploaded a CSV file containing my products which also includes the image gallery column, which contains the corresponding image URL. The Problem is that it appears that these images are not attached to the products and the URL's of the images in my media file return a 404 page.

Any help would be much appreciated, thankyou Alex.